# How to search only within the displayed map with google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gmaps4rails

Airbnb has a feature on their main search page that only the results in the map are shown. Is it something that is supported by the google maps api ?

I am using the gem [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails). I havn't found this in neither in the google maps api not in the gem.

Basically what I want is the bounds of the map so that I know what constraints to search with, so that the results fit in the map.

How do you think it can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Map-class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#Map) has a method called getBounds().